# Windows Embedded Compact 2013 - Initial Application Focus

Tags: c++, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, windows-embedded-compact, blend-2012

I have a log in screen when my application starts and would like the cursor to be waiting in the user name text box to type (without clicking). I was able to focus the cursor after the grid loads:

```
HRESULT MainPage::OnLoaded(__in IXRDependencyObject* pRoot)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pRoot);

    HRESULT hr = InitializeComponent();

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto Error;
    }

    if (m_pLogin)
    {
        m_pLogin->AddLoadedEventHandler(CreateDelegate(this, &MainPage::Login_Loaded));
    }
Error:
    return hr;
} // OnLoaded

HRESULT MainPage::Login_Loaded (IXRDependencyObject* pSender, XRRoutedEventArgs* pArgs)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    m_pUserName->Focus(&pBool);

    return hr;
}
```

This allows me to type but the cursor isn't actually visible.

I have seen other threads explaining that the browser plugin must have focus first, but this is an embedded silverlight application (C++) and not a silverlight webpage (C#). I cannot figure out how to set focus to the application when it starts without using the mouse. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to accomplish this without a mouse click - but I used [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to synthesize a mouse click so the user doesn't have to.

```
HRESULT MainPage::OnLoaded(__in IXRDependencyObject* pRoot)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pRoot);

    HRESULT hr = InitializeComponent();

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto Error;
    }

    if (m_pLogin)
    {
        m_pLogin->AddLoadedEventHandler(CreateDelegate(this, &MainPage::Login_Loaded));
        m_pLogin->AddMouseLeftButtonUpEventHandler(CreateDelegate(this, &MainPage::Login_MouseLeftButtonUp));
    }
Error:
    return hr;
} // OnLoaded

HRESULT MainPage::Login_Loaded (IXRDependencyObject* pSender, XRRoutedEventArgs* pArgs)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // execute mouse click
    INPUT ip;
    ip.type = INPUT_MOUSE;

    ip.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
    SendInput(1,&ip,sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
    SendInput(1,&ip,sizeof(INPUT));

    return hr;
}

HRESULT MainPage::Login_MouseLeftButtonUp (IXRDependencyObject* pSender, XRMouseButtonEventArgs* pArgs)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    m_pUserName->Focus(&pBool);

    return hr;
}
```